# PgAdmin on Ubuntu 20.04 FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've installed Postgres and PGAdmin4 on Ubuntu 20.04, but I'm not able to create a server and connect to the database

[image]

As I have seen in several solutions, I changed the method to md5 on my pg_hba.conf file

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I have as well connected to psql, created new users, alter password and restart the server by running `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look in the servers log file for the complete error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

Input your sudo user password

```
psql
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'new_password';
\q
exit
```

Now change config file to use this new password:

```
sudo subl /etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf
```

(`subl` means subliime text, you can use any other text editor).

Edit this part of the file: change peer to md5

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

restart the postgres service

Run this command to sign into postgres using the newly created password:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Comment: Hi, do you know why I tried above procedure. (retried about 5 times and restarted server). Placed password in single quote for "ALTER USER..." as shown above when creating the password and still receive "psql: error: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" when performing "psql -U postgres"? UPDATE: Nevermind! I was able to fix by setting the password with \password instead of using ALTER USER!

Comment: Using the `\password` answer is correct, and this only works really if you keep the METHOD for USER postgres as 'peer', so the solution above is wrong. I would also add that for other users, it should indeed be set to md5 (or `password`, which worked in my case), but that is insufficient. You also need to GRANT privileges to the role to be able to log in, I'm guessing CONNECT is the one if you're doing it through SQL -- I did that through pgAdmin GUI.

Answer (score 2):

1. First we have to get inside postgres by using

   `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`
2. Enter password for user postgres

Now the terminal will be like this:

postgres=#

3. Now enter the given line after postgres=#
   `CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'your password';`
   (put your password inside quotes('') and don't forget semicolon(;)

Answer (score 1):

sudo -u postgres psql
and set new password
postgres=# \password

Source of solution:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ej08u5xPa64

Comment: Please refrain from posting video links. You could have explained it here as well!